# Keep observable connected even with no subscribers

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

EDIT 2: What worked even better was `shareReplay(1)`, as stated in the update of [@karser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686021/4811678).

---

EDIT 1: What ended up working best was this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGlobalService {

  private resource$;
  private resource$Connected;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.resource$Connected = false;
    this.resource$ = this.http
      .get('/api/resource')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .publishReplay(1);
  } 

  getResource(): Observable<any> {
    if (!this.resource$Connected) {
      this.resource$.connect();
      this.resource$Connected = true;
    }
    return this.resource$;
  }

}
```

It only makes the AJAX call once, and it doesn't call until some consumer requires the resource.

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm trying to cache an angular HTTP call and multicast the most recent result to all current and future subscribers. The ajax results won't change over the application lifetime, so I don't want to make any extra calls for a resource I already have. Therefore, I want it to continue to stay "connected" even when all the subscribers unsubscribe. Is this possible?

What I initially tried was this:

```
// in a global service 

getResource(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http
    .get('/api/resource')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .publishLast()
    .refCount();
}
```

This works well for multiple `async` pipes in the same component, but if that component is destroyed (and thus `refCount` goes to 0) the HTTP request will be repeated on a later instantiation of the component.

To combat this, I started manually caching the results:

```
resourceResults: any;

getResource(): Observable<any> {
  if (resourceResults) {
    return Observable.of(this.resourceResults);
  }
  return this.http
    .get('/api/resource')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .do(x => this.resourceResults = x)
    .publishLast()
    .refCount();
}
```

This works fine, but I feel like there is a more rx way to do it.

I've tried using `connect()`, but that seems to suffer the same issue as my first example. Once all the subscribers have unsubscribed, using `connect()` causes the HTTP request to happen again

```
resource$ = this.http
  .get('/api/resource')
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .publishLast()
  .refCount();

getResource(): Observable<any> {
  this.resource$.connect();
  return this.resource$;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just an idea, could you keep a dummy subscriber up and running in the same component/service that the observable lives in? That way the subscription would never be zero, and you could use .share(). The only way the subscription could zero out is if the component/service/whatever containing the observer itself was destroyed. Wrapping the observable logic such that calls to unsubscribe would be gated would ensure that single subscriber was never removed and so on. I have no idea if it's a good idea, but it could be a practical one.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do exactly what I was trying to do 9 months ago :D
I would like to collaborate on this a little bit more, but I do not remember that much from 9 months ago :( You can check the repo, since it solves all the issues you mentioned and some more too :)
I have published a package to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/observable-api) ([github](https://github.com/lneicelis/observable-api)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

publishReplay/connect works. Here is [the working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bgSX1ZjSNGEovw9YSwrZ?p=preview):

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class YourService {
    resource:Observable<any>;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.resource = this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/karser')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .do(res => console.log('response', res))
            .publishReplay(1);
        this.resource.connect();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Subscribing
response Object {login: "karser", id: 1675033…}
Unscibscribed
Subscribing once again
```

UPDATE: RxJS 5.4 has [shareReplay](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md) operator which apparently does the same thing. See [the updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCxtWbhStCnggjgjD0ne?p=preview)

```
this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/karser')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .shareReplay(1);
```

From [pull request](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2443#issue-211913196):

> `shareReplay` returns an observable that is the source multicasted
>   over a `ReplaySubject`. That replay subject is recycled on error from
>   the source, but not on completion of the source. This makes
>   `shareReplay` ideal for handling things like caching AJAX results, as
>   it's retryable. It's repeat behavior, however, differs from share in
>   that it will not repeat the source observable, rather it will repeat
>   the source observable's values.

Comment: The docs say it "shares that subscription with all subsequent observers until the number of observers returns to zero, at which point the subscription is disposed." What I'm hoping for is a way to keep it from disposing itself, even after observers returns to zero.

Comment: This didn't _quite_ solve my use case because I didn't want to connect until the last moment, but it's a valid answer and put me on the right path. Thanks! I've update the question to show the slight adjustment that did work.

Comment: @WillHowell Did you try shareReplay? You don't need resource$Connected in this case. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yessss! `shareReplay` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for keeping an eye on the changelog!

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to share this response during the entire application lifetime you should put it into a service and make sure you all your components are sharing the same instance.

You could theoretically make the source Observable to never complete. To be more precise you could make just the chain to never propage the complete signal but this is not recommended and potentially lead to unexpected behavior if you tried to use this Observable with operators such `forkJoin()` or `toArray()` and any similar that require the source Observable to properly complete.

Instead you can use `publishReplay(1)` to keep the last value emitted by the source Observable, `refCount()` to hold a single subscription to the source Observable while the cache is being queried and then `take(1)` to accept only one value and complete.

```
const cache = this.http.get('/api/resource')
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()
  .take(1);
```

So you can subscribe multiple observers at once and only one HTTP request will be performed. Then any subsequent subscriptions will hit the `.publishReplay(1)` that already has a cached value which is immediately propagated and `take(1)` completes the chain right away. So there'll be no subscription to `this.http.get('/api/resource')` and therefore no request will be made.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use refCount. Create connectable observable manually, do connect, subscribe on it and ReplaySubject of the connectable will keep the last published value. Something like that:

```
let obs$ = Rx.Observable.interval(5000)
  .multicast(new Rx.ReplaySubject(1));

obs$.connect();

// unsuscribe when service is destroyed???
let mainSubecription = obs$.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));

// create subscription (like async pipe)
let subscription;
setTimeout(()=> {
  subscription = obs$.subscribe(x=>console.log('second', x));
}, 15000);


// remove subscription (like async pipe)
setTimeout(()=> {
 subscription.unsubscribe();
}, 40000);

// the main subscription still gets data
```